# Information from a characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

(III) I know that since the highest multiplicity is 4, that the largest possible dimension is 4.

(IV) I believe that there are 3 distinct eigenvalues, but because of the multiplicities, there are exactly 7 eigenvalues?

I don't know how to tell if it's invertible, or the size of the matrix from the information given.

Comment: 0 is an eigenvalue so that $Ax=0$ has non-trivial solutions.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is $\mathrm{det}(A-\lambda I)$. How does the degree of this depend on the size of the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I): $A$ can't be invertible because $0$ is an eigenvalue.

(II): $A$ must be $7 \times 7$ because its characteristic polynomial has degree $7$.

(III): Your answer is correct

(IV): I don't think that they mean to count eigenvalues up to multiplicity.  Yes, $A$ has exactly $3$ distinct eigenvalues.